# AngularJs : Check some fields are valid then fire ajax and populate the select html

Tags: angularjs

I've a form below

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="req_appmt" id="req_appmt" novalidate ng-submit="SendAppointmentRequest()">

  <div class="form-group" ng-class="(req_appmt.form_comments.$error.required) ? 'has-error' : '' ">
    <label for="form_comments" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Reason for Appointment* :</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10"><textarea id="form_comments" name="form_comments" ng-model="formdata.form_comments" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea></div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-class="(req_appmt.physician_id.$error.required) ? 'has-error' : '' ">
    <label for="physician_id" class="col-lg-2 control-label">To* :</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <select name="physician_id" ng-model="formdata.physician_id" id="physician_id" class="form-control" required>
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <option ng-repeat="physician in physicians" value="{{physician.id}}">{{physician.fullname}}</option>
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group" ng-class="(req_appmt.date.$error.required) ? 'has-error' : '' ">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date :</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
     <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="formdata.date" name="date" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" close-text="Close" required="required" ng-click="open($event)">

        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
     </p>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group" ng-class="(req_appmt.time.$error.required) ? 'has-error' : '' ">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Free Slot :</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <select name="time" ng-model="formdata.time" id="time" class="form-control" required>
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <!-- <option ng-repeat="key,value in slots" value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option> -->
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10"><p>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-success">Request Appointment</button>
  <a href="pendingappointments" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-warning">Cancel</a>
</p> </div> </div>
  </form>
```

This is my controller :

```
ModuleEvents.controller('ctrlRequestAppointment', function ($location,$scope,$http,$rootScope,$cookies,ServiceCheckAuth,ServiceEvents){
    /*First check patient is logged in*/
    if( !ServiceCheckAuth.isPatientLoggedIn() ){ 
        $location.url('/login'); 
        return;
    }
    /*Set rootScope values*/
    $rootScope.root = {
        html_title:HTML_TITLE_PATIENT_APPOINTMENT_REQUEST,
        loggedin:true,
        activeNxtstp:'active',
        customclass:'content_inner_im w-100-mob'
    };
    var json_physicians = localStorage.getItem('physicians');
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
    $scope.date = new Date();

    $scope.physicians = JSON.parse(json_physicians);
    $scope.formdata = {};

    $scope.opened = false;
    $scope.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.$watch(req_appmt.date.$valid, function() {

        if( req_appmt.date.$valid && req_appmt.physician_id.$valid ){
            console.log($scope.formdata);
        }
    });

    $scope.SendAppointmentRequest = function(){
        if( $scope.req_appmt.$valid ){
            console.log($scope.formdata);
        }
    }

});
```

What I'm trying :

1) User selects To field in the form
2) then user selects date field in the form
3) then I want to check in controller both are filled and validated
4) then I want to fire a ajax request that will populate the Free Slot field of he form

Problem : 
I can not check whether the fields are valid

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You should never access to $rootScope and neither do $watch unless really necessary.

Comment: As per my knowledge one should not use $rootScope with variables that update the data... we can use it for variables that just used in view template.

Comment: Sure you can use them, it is just a bad practice.
It is not related with your problem, which I can not check right now.

Comment: @CarlosBarcelona what is harm is using $watch..just curious ..

Comment: @AngularLerner $scope will disappear at Angular 2 and there are good reasons behind. Here is a blog post that explains it very nicely http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html

Answer (score 1):

can you use an function() which can validate all fields of formdata like

```
$scope.function_name=function()
{
    var validatefalg=true;
    if($scope.formdata.physician_id!='')
    {
        validatefalg=false;
        return validatefalg;
    }
    else
    {        
        return validatefalg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with the help of @jyotsna :

```
if( $scope.req_appmt.physician_id.$valid && $scope.req_appmt.date.$valid ){}
```